# What does SAN means in the context of Solace MQ?

Tags: solace-mq, solace

While exploring the Solace's MQ product, I came across the term **SAN**:

> "When receiving applications are disconnected or can’t keep up with the
>   flow of messages, their backlog is pushed to a **SAN**".

From: http://solacesystems.com/products/mq-messaging

I assume it's somehow relates to memory storage, but I would be happy to get a full explanation about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't "Storage Area Network"?  ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storage_area_network )

Answer (score 4):

In this context SAN does indeed mean Storage Area Network. The Solace Message Routers can store messages marked as persistent on storage that is attached to the Solace appliances via a fibre channel Storage Area Network.